# Determine whether a statement holds in Bayesian network

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

Given the following bayesian network:

[image: Bayesian network with 9 parameters]

I have to determine whether the following statement holds:

$P(B, H | E, G) = P(B | E, G) * P(H | E, G)$.

Is it true that this statement is valid when $B \bot H$? I don't really know which formula can be applied to a conditional probability of 2 joint probabilities, as is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true since $B$ and $H$ are conditionally independent given $G$, and $G$ is a given. The definition of independence is that $P(A, B) = P(A) * P(B)$

You could further prove this out by writing the probability for the whole system, summing over all the unwanted nodes, then saying that $P(H|G)$ is independent of its parents since $G$ is given. So $P(B, H|G) = P(B) * P(H|G)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I did not know about that, thanks!

Comment: Why don't we need to consider E also? Is it enough to determine that B and H are conditionally independent given G?

Comment: I believe so. Knowing G blocks the "path" between B and H, thus making them independent. E does not do that.